# Problem with DateTime in Asp.net Core Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, npgsql

The `DateTime` field is defined in the token's Claim, however when I try to retrieve it's value it does not exist, I know there is a problem when saving `DateTime`in Postgres due to time zones. My `Program.cs`:

```
...
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = 
    JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["SymmetricSecurityKey"])),
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("IdadeMinima", policy =>
        policy.AddRequirements(new IdadeMinima(18)));
});

builder.Services.AddDbContext<UsuarioDbContext>(
    opts => opts.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:UsuarioConnection"]));

builder.Services.AddIdentity<Usuario, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UsuarioDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, IdadeAuthorization>();
...
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

My `TokenService.cs`:

```
public class UsuarioDbContext: IdentityDbContext<Usuario>
{
    public UsuarioDbContext(DbContextOptions<UsuarioDbContext> opts): base(opts){}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<Usuario>().Property(props => props.DataNascimento).HasColumnType("timestamp without time zone");
    }
}
```

My `UsuarioProfile.cs` translation `UserProfile.cs`

```
public UsuarioProfile()
{
    CreateMap<CreateUsuarioDTO, Usuario>();
}
```

Used Packages
Id ,                                 Versions,                             ProjectName

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.St..., {7.0.11},UsuarioApi                                                                                                                        
AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft...., {12.0.1},UsuarioApi                                                                                                                                           
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt,    {7.0.0},UsuarioApi                                                                                                                                         
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authenticat..., {6.0.22},UsuarioApi                                                                                                                                            
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.En..., {6.0.22},UsuarioApi                                                                                                                                            
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore,              {6.5.0},UsuarioApi                                                                                                                                                
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.Postg..., {7.0.11},UsuarioApi                                                                                                                                             
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.Postg..., {1.1.0},UsuarioApi                                                                                                                                         
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, {7.0.11},UsuarioApi                                 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools, {7.0.11},UsuarioApi
```

I changed the field from `DateTime` to `DateTimeOffset` following the documentation in `npgsql`.

Comment: The title also has to be written in english